# How to get the Group Id of symbian using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I got the group names by using

```
ContactList clist=(ContactList)pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_WRITE);

String[] s=clist.getCategories();
```

and now i want the groupid like i am getting the contact id using Contact.uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such thing as Group Id in JSR-75, I'm afraid. Categories are just String.